# Higmaps doesn't display states of certain country

Tags: jquery, highmaps

I'm using Highmaps - Rich information on click. On the site the demo is a map of the world but I'm trying to just use the states of the country Colombia. I haven't been able to get Highmaps to display the data, it only displays one state and I need it to display all of the states. I already included the correct map:

```
var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/co/co-all']);
```

Heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antonioj1015/ff2m2bsx/) with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work...Whats wrong is that when saving a CVS file thorugh excel, it will add double quotes, so in excel it would appear "Text1","Text2" id a text editor it would appear ""Text1"",""Text2""...I just had to remove that extra double qoute...